# reload tab in google chrome without flicker

Tags: google-chrome

**Is there a way to configure google chrome to reload a tab without flickering?**

I.e load the page in the background then immediately switch over to it.

The content of the page I am loading stays largely the same, but as the page refreshes, I have to watch the whole page load over and over again.

I've tried looking through the extensive list of [command line paramaters](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), and taken a peek at the [developer how-to's](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos), but I can't find anything.